# pound symbol in inequalities

Tags: inequality, notation, systems-of-equations

a friend of mine has to solve some equations, but in some of them appears something like a pound symbol. Do you know what it means and how to solve it? or the teacher really lose his wit?

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: The only thing I could think of at all that in terms of similarity would be $\leq$, but that's really a reach. I think it's a typo as well.

Comment: I'm guessing it should be ${} < {}$, but only reading that textbook can tell us for sure. (On a Mac keyboard, £ is option-3, while ‹ is option-shift-3.  Maybe they are similar in other settings, too.)

Comment: Probably a typo

Comment: The teacher  lost $\frac{1}{2}$ his wit. There is a saying (this isn't verbatim): "Those that can do, do. Those that can't do, teach. Those that can't teach, go into administration." :)

Comment: If they're question numbers, $71,73,75$, then $71$ is the most puzzling. If pound were an equals sign you might have to solve an equation, and inequality then maybe sketch the solution interval, so in either of these cases $71$ involves minimal work.